# Large WooCommerce query throws fatal memory errors

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, wordpress-hook

I have a site that has tens of thousands of orders, which I need to compare the billing and customer/user emails and show a flag if they don't match. One of the stipulations is that I'm unable to add any metadata to the orders. So my solution is to just add a custom column, and compare the emails on the fly when the orders list is rendered. That works just fine.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'mismatched_orders_column' ); 

function mismatched_orders_column( $columns ) {

    $columns['mismatched'] = 'Mismatched';
    return $columns;

}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'mismatched_orders_column_data' );

function mismatched_orders_column_data( $column ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'mismatched' === $column ) {

        $order    = new WC_Order( $post->ID );
        $customer = $order->get_user();

        $result = '';

        $billing_email = strtolower ( $order->get_billing_email() );
        $customer_email = '';

        if ($customer) $customer_email = strtolower ( $customer->user_email );

        if ( $customer && ( $billing_email != $customer_email ) ) {

            $result = '<span class="mismatched-order" title="Possible order mismatch">Yes</span>';

        }

        echo $result;
    }
}
```

My issue is when trying to add sorting. Because I'm not accessing any post metadata, I don't have any easy data to sort via the main query. My solution here was originally to hook into `pre_get_posts`, grab all the orders in a new `WP_Query`, then loop through them and add the ones that had mismatched emails to an array for use in `post__in`.

This works/worked fine on my small dev site, but throws fatal memory errors when trying to loop over any more than about 8 or 9 thousand posts (out of a total of 30-40 thousand). Increasing memory isn't really an option.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns', 'mismatched_orders_column_sortable');

function mismatched_orders_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['mismatched'] = 'mismatched';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mismatched_emails_posts_orderby' );

function mismatched_emails_posts_orderby( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    //Remove the pre_get_posts hook so we don't get stuck in a loop
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mismatched_emails_posts_orderby' );

    //Make sure we're only looking at our custom column
    if ( 'mismatched' === $query->get( 'orderby') ) {

        //Set our initial array for 'post__in'
        $mismatched = array();

        $orders_list = get_posts(array(
            'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_status'       => 'any',
            'fields'            => 'ids'
        ));

        //And here is our problem
        foreach( $orders_list as $order_post ) :

            //Get our order and customer/user object
            $order_object = new WC_Order( $order_post );
            $customer = $order_object->get_user();

            //Check that billing and customer emails don't match, and also that we're not dealing with a guest order
            if ( ( $order_object->get_billing_email() != $customer->user_email ) && $order_object->get_user() != false ) {

                $mismatched[] = $order_post;

            }

        endforeach;  wp_reset_postdata();

        $query->set( 'post__in', $mismatched );

    }
}
```

I would seriously appreciate any insight into how I could either reduce the expense of the query I'm trying to run, or an alternate approach. Again, just for clarification, adding metadata to the orders isn't an option.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realized I probably don't need `setup_postdata`, considering I'm only retrieving ids, and I only need ids...

Comment: After doing some more research, I think I've learned that doing a query like that on thousands of posts is just a bad idea in general.

Comment: Obviously a better way to do this would be to `$query->set('meta_key')` or `$query->set('meta_array')`, but because the customer email isn't stored as metadata for the order, I can't (I don't think) access it to run a query against `_billing_email`. All I have to work with is `_customer_user`, which gives me a user ID.

Comment: Why are you using pre_get_posts?

Comment: Mostly because I'm trying to alter the main query and preserve the default pagination/sorting. Definitely open to alternatives/suggestions though. Currently exploring the `posts_where` `filter`, although SQL is a bit outside my comfort zone.

Comment: Is this like a one time thing, or you have to do this on an ongoing basis? It sounds like it's a one time thing?

Comment: Using it to hook into the sorting functionality of a custom column. I should probably edit and add more code.

Comment: Please do. Put all relevant code, so I can check it out myself.

Comment: Done, added the custom column code (works), should provide more context. Also removed `setup_postdata()`, although it didn't end up saving enough resources to make a difference.

Comment: So 'mismatched' is defined by `get_billing_email() !== $user->email right`?  So, foreach $order - get the billing email, and check it against the user data user email?

Comment: Exactly, any idea how to get the user email in the main query? I'm fairly certain it can be done via SQL, but it's beyond me how to build the queries. Tried tapping into `posts_where` and `posts_join`, but I'm out of my depth there.

Comment: The problem with your query that you want to execute is that you have to join 3 tables to get an `order` (posts) where `meta_key` `_customer_user` > 0 and where if the user is > 0 - find their email (from user table) and compare the two.  I don't think there's any way to slice this without it being a slow query.  Inability to create a meta value is a strange request.  What about running this query in the background, and storing the values in a transient?  Have it update the transient value (your posts_in array) after a new order is placed?

Comment: The reason it can't be stored in an `custom field` is that it's a tool for them to see which existing orders are mismatched, and writing `metadata` to 10's of thousands of posts in the background is out of scope (and also room for a lot of error).

For the table joins, looked at that yesterday, hooking into `posts_where` and `posts_join`, but my knowledge of `SQL` was making it laborious. It should work in theory, as the `limit` (20 records by default, 999 max) shouldn't be an issue. Guessing this is probably about the point where I should post another question?

Comment: I posted a new question specifically concerning filtering the SQL query here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363962/sql-joins-not-getting-correct-columns